# stretchable tableview header with small content size

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a table view with stretchable header like in the following example : "https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/how-to-create-a-stretchable-tableviewheader-in-ios-ee9ed049aba3". The example works great when the content size of the table is big. but when I change the number of rows in section to 5 the the header is not collapsing.
So to summeries the question. I want to make a stretchable table header that will behave as follow:
if I scroll up it will try to collapse till some min limit (lets say 50 point).
if I scroll down it will expand till max limit (lets say 200 point). It should work even if there is only one cell

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve this by adding a content inset. After the table view is reloaded you should be able to get its content size using `contentSize` property and can compute the offset you need. You don't want to set to negative values but the end result should look something like the following:

```
var insets = tableView.contentInset
inset.bottom = max(0, tableView.bounds.height-tableView.contentSize.height)
tableView.contentInset = insets
```

Comment: It will solve it but it will cause a difficult to maintain this behavior. the inset should be updated on insert/remove/update or with cells that have an automatic dimension. when working as part of a team it can cause lots of bugs because it is very easy to forget

Comment: @GenaNovak Agreed but unfortunately most of the UIKit comes to that when you need something that it was not designed for. If you need this more generally you might actually be able to subclass the tableview and try to solve it there. Try overriding the contentSize property for instance. I am not sure it will work at least for all cases but if you play around a bit more you might be able to accomplish it...